# Provide Mosquitto password file from outisde Docker container

Tags: docker, mosquitto

I am succesfully starting mosquitto with following docker command.

```
docker run -it --name mosquitto -p 1883:1883 --rm -v /home/ec2-user/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf - eclipse-mosquitto
```

I am also using this configuration lines to connect mqtt broker;

```
persistence false
allow_anonymous false
connection_messages true
log_type all
listener 1883
```

**What I am trying to do;**

I am trying to provide a password_file outside container like I provide configuration file.

**What I've tried so far**

After container created successfully with previous docker command, I created password file inside container(docker exec -it *id* bin/sh) and copied whats inside of the password file in another file outside container.

And after that I added  password_file

```
 password_file /etc/mosquitto/passwordfile
```

to the configuration and tried the docker command below

```
docker run -it --name mosquitto -p 1883:1883 --rm -v /home/ec2-user/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf:/mosquitto/config/mosquitto.conf -v /home/ec2-user/mosquitto/password/passwordfile:/etc/mosquitto/passwordfile eclipse-mosquitto
```

**Result**

```
1706733322: Error: Unable to open pwfile "/etc/mosquitto/passwordfile".
1706733322: Error opening password file "/etc/mosquitto/passwordfile".
```

**Goal;**

I am trying to store password file outside of docker container, it's because servers changes time to time, so copying a password file would be easy job to do.

I am open to any suggestions and any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

***EDIT- Found solution***

The problem was providing wrong address for passwordfile...

Comment: You might want to google what "/etc/passwd" is before you decide to replace it... that's the password file for the entire Linux instance, not Mosquitto. Have you read the error message? It makes it clear where it's looking for the password file, and it's not "/etc/passwd".

Comment: It throws same error for any path or file. It's my mistake, copy/paste error. I edited the question.  @romkey

Comment: What are the permissions on the file on the host system and what UID:GID owns the file? Are these readable by the user running mosquitto inside the container?

Comment: I am not good at linux but, with ls -l, I saw that pasword file has -rw------- 1 and owner of the file is ec2-user(aws user)